# I am getting error " networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod" on deploying pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am new to Kubernetes. Just set up the stack one master and another slave ( two Ec2 Instances ) when trying to deploy my first pod on the slave I got below error. Could you hlep me out. Error file is attached.

**Error:**

> Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  34m                     kubelet, slave-node  Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "26cdaf3170806455a4731218d20c482bb2a41ded6ef85c90b560058e332df684" network for pod "label-demo": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "label-demo_default" network: open /run/flannel/subnet.env: no such file or directory

Comment: have you deployed flannel? is it running in kube-system namespace? Provide output of kubectl get pods -n kube-system

Comment: How exactly did you create your cluster? Was it created with `kubeadm` or something like `kubespray`?

Comment: ubuntu@master-node:~$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-6955765f44-d8fw9              1/1     Running   8          27h
coredns-6955765f44-l5cjz              1/1     Running   2          27h
etcd-master-node                      1/1     Running   3          27h

Comment: I set up my cluster using Kubeadm

Comment: Please take a look on this comment on [Github.com: Kubernetes Flannel](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/70202#issuecomment-481173403) and let me know if it helped. Additionally please update your post with information like `kubectl get nodes -o wide` and `kubectl get pods -A`

Answer (score 1):

As the state of this cluster, how exactly it was deployed as well as the output messages of `kubectl`, `kubelet` are unknown, I will try to give some troubleshooting steps and circumstances that can lead to resolving some of the problems that are encountered here.

- Kubeadm
- Flannel
- Kubelet
- Reproduction
- Additional links

#### Kubeadm

The first thing is provisioning process of the Kubernetes cluster with `kubeadm`:

Check all the requirements and steps with official documentation:

- [Kubernetes.io: Install kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/).
- [Kubernetes.io: Create cluster kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/)

When invoking `$ kubeadm init` command please make sure to add parameters like:

- `--apiserver-advertise-address=IP_ADDRESS_OF_MASTER_NODE`
- `--pod-network-cidr=POD_NETWORK_CIDR_WITH_ACCORDANCE_TO_CNI`

**Provisioning cluster without `--pod-network-cidr` parameter could lead to CNI related issues.**

For Flannel default pod network cidr is `10.244.0.0/16`.

After `kubeadm init` you need to apply one of many CNI's (like Flannel or Calico) as the `kubeadm` tool does not do it automatically.

Please check if all of the nodes are in `Ready` status with command:

`$ kubectl get nodes -o wide`

Output of this command should look like that:

```sh
NAME   STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
k1     Ready    master   69m   v1.17.3   10.156.0.29   <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS   5.0.0-1031-gcp   docker://19.3.7
k2     Ready    <none>   65m   v1.17.3   10.156.0.30   <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS   5.0.0-1031-gcp   docker://19.3.7
k3     Ready    <none>   63m   v1.17.3   10.156.0.35   <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS   5.0.0-1031-gcp   docker://19.3.7
```

Additionally you can `$ kubectl describe node NAME_OF_THE_NODE` to get more detailed information about each of the nodes.

#### Flannel

There is official documentation about troubleshooting Flannel related issues: [Github.com: flannel troubleshooting](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/troubleshooting.md)

The message that you received from `kubelet`:

> Warning FailedCreatePodSandBox 34m kubelet, slave-node Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "26cdaf3170806455a4731218d20c482bb2a41ded6ef85c90b560058e332df684" network for pod "label-demo": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "label-demo_default" network: open /run/flannel/subnet.env: no such file or directory

Is telling that there is `subnet.env` file missing on a node that was supposed to schedule a `sandbox` pod.

Furthermore please check if Flannel pods are running correctly. You can check it with either:

- `$ kubectl get pods -A`
- `$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system`

Additionally you can check logs of this pods by running command: 
`$ kubectl logs NAME_OF_FLANNEL_CONTAINER`

#### Kubelet

You can check `kubelet` logs by (on systemd os) with:

- `$ systemctl status kubelet`
- `$ journalctl -u kubelet`

#### Reproduction

I've managed to reproduce error that you encountered and it was happening when:

- `--pod-network-cidr=CIDR` was not used with `$ kubeadm init`
- Flannel CNI was applied after `$ kubeadm init` without `--pod-network-cidr`

#### Additional links:

There is an article talking about troubleshooting networking: [Kubernetes.feisky.xyz: Network](https://kubernetes.feisky.xyz/v/en/index/network).

Please let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: Thanks, Dawid
Your information is really helpful. I resolved the issue by reinstalling the cluster in a different way.